# Кириллица в массивах типа char в C++

Tags: c++

Инициализирую массив так -

```
char h[7] = {'п', 'р', 'и', 'в', 'е', 'т', '\0'};
```

Всё хорошо компилируется, но когда я инициализирую вот так:

```
char h[7] = "привет"; // 7 элемент для нуля
```

То MS Visual Studio 2010 говорит мол:

> `1 IntelliSense: значение типа "const char [13]" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "char [7]"    c:\users\руслан\desktop\c++\инициализация массивов\инициализация массивов\main.cpp  10  15  Инициализация массивов`

Понял что char может содержат символы из ASCII таблицы, где русских букв нет. Но программа компилируется, и даже можно прочитать этот массив. Где-то прочитал что символы кириллицы кодируется 16 битами, в отличие от символов из ASCII. Если так, то значит и первый вариант инициализации массива может потревожит рядом стоящие байты памяти? И как оно так, в 8-рязрядную переменную 16-разрядное значение?

Comment: Ужасть! Кто его знает, как символы кириллицы кодируются в MS VS 2010. Кодировки бывают разные. Есть несколько 8мибитных кодировок с кириллицей: (наиболее распространённые: koi8-r, cp866 (dos), cp1251(win)). Есть юникод с кучей вариантов представления, в т.ч. символы постоянной длины, напр ucs-2 (эти самые 16бит), переменной (наиболее популярен utf-8 -- переменное количество байт). А как оно в MS VS...

Comment: вон оно что :)

Comment: вы уверены, что точно понимаете, что именно делаете в этой строке?

Comment: В вариант с юникодом как-то слабо верится. Для него есть отдельный тип wchar_t, да и строка без модификатора L. Меня больше интересует, зачем указывать размер массива цифрой, когда это не требуется. Пусть будет себе такой длины, как хочет :D Попробуйте вывести его на экран, интересно, что будет) Он же должен будет его выводить, как обычный char. Только правда перед этим нужно поколдовать с локалью)

Comment: @Супер герой В первом объявлении в массиве символов нет завершающего нуля или это просто искажение отображения? Что там в конце: `'0'` или `'\0'`? А во втором объявлении уберите число. Транслятор сам подставит.

Comment: Вечная тема "почему на экране крякозябры"?

Comment: @alexlz Кракозябры.. :D У нас лектор по ЯВУ очень любила это слово))) Но я не помню, чтобы у меня были какие-то проблемы с локалью. Хотя дело было давно конечно))

Comment: Заверщающий символ там слеш и 0, не отображает тут просто почему-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто надо разобраться с самим понятием массива строк. в первом случае вы объявляете массив из 7 символов и каждому элементу массива присваиваете конкретное значение. А втором варианте вы пытаетесь заставить компилятор сделать это за вас. поэтому опустите размерность массива - в данном случае она не нужна.

ЗЫ Рекомендуемый список литературы:

1. [Массивы символов](http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/c/c2/book011.htm)
2. [Массивы С++](http://shatalov.su/ru/articles/cpp_primer/array.php) - см. раздел Строки
3. [Типы переменных](http://azbukavb.narod.ru/cdoc/types.html)

Comment: Только массив символов наверно. Массив строк это разве не 
<pre>char w[длинна строк][длина символов строки] = {"square", "triangle"};</pre>

Comment: да, конечно массив символов)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так все работает:

```
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
      setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian");    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
      char mas[7]="Привет";
      cout<<mas;
  }
```